# Sorting Chinese names in iOS UITableview

Tags: uitableview, ios8, chinese-locale

I want to sort my table view data based on pinyin of Chinese characters. How would I do this ? I did sort it but when it sorts it just divide all sections into characters what I want is when it sorts into sections it take pinyin and sort it with alphabetical order not with characters.  And I can also use section Index ABCDEF....XYZ# to go to different sections. Right now it starts adding characters both in section and section index.

Comment: @Renzo I did sort it but when it sorts it just divide all sections into characters what I want is when it sorts into sections it take pinyin and sort it with alphabetical order not with characters

Answer (score 2):

CoreFoundation provides transform method to convert from Chinese to PinYin:

```swift
import CoreFoundation

func stringPinYin(src: String) -> String {
    let stringRef = NSMutableString(string: src) as CFMutableString
    CFStringTransform(stringRef, nil, kCFStringTransformToLatin, false)
    CFStringTransform(stringRef, nil, kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, false)
    return stringRef as String
}
```

`中文` -> `zhong wen`